# mod_rewrite code returns wrong domain, changed symbolic link to actual

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains for the same website.

I have a single page on my site I want to appear to come from the second domain (in this example it is **example2.com/pagex**). With exception to root and pagex, all other requests to **example2.com** should be redirected to **example1.com**.

All pages on my site appear as directories but are really just **index.php?page=pagename** due to mod_rewrite rules shown below.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ #Do not redirect root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pagex/ #Do not redirect pagex
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301]

# If the file or folder does not exist, send to index.php as variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Running the above code by going to **example2.com/pagex/**  I get redirected to **www.example1.com/index.php?page=pagex**. The second condition should have failed, preventing the redirect. What is even stranger is the virtual directory has been replaced with the actual path.

Comment: So, `/pagex/` is an actual directory that exists?

Comment: `/pagex/` is not an actual directory. It is `index.php?page=pagex` being masked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pagex/? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://www.example1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# If the file or folder does not exist, send to index.php as variable
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

With above code `http://example2.com/pagex/` gets correctly redirected to `http://example2.com/index.php?page=pagex`

Comment: I am trying to get http://example2.com/pagex not to redirect at all, it is all the other pages on the site I want to redirect. I also tested the code you provided and still redirects it to http://example1.com/index.php?page=pagex (not example2).

Comment: If that is the case then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pagex/ [NC]` will be needed in 2nd redirect rule as well. I just updated my answer, pls try again.

Comment: I get this response: `#1 Server Response: example2.com/pagex/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2011 04:13:18 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.example1.com/missing.html
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: `missing.html` is NOT there in above rules. Do you have some other rules firing in from somewhere or else you may have `ErrorDocument 404 http://example1.com/missing.html` somewhere.

Comment: There is nothing else in my `.htaccess` file. Though `ErrorDocument 404 http://example1.com/missing.html` is probably part of the hosts `httpd.conf` file, but I do not have access to it to verify.

Comment: Fair enough. But from web server log you can see that `/pagex/` got escaped from both the rules as you desired because 1. It didn't become `exampple1.com/pagex/` and 2. It didn't become `/index.php?page=pagex`. So rules worked fine. However some other setting is returning 301 to `missing.html` which obviously above rules can't control. Are you sure you have a directory called `/pagex/` in the DOCUMENT_ROOT of `example2.com`?

Comment: `/pagex/` does not exist. It is created from `index.php?page=pagex` using the mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Ah I think I got confused after your first comment and thought you don't even want 2nd rule to be applied for `/pagex/` URI. I modified it again, pls try and let me know.

Comment: Applied the fix. It now redirects to `http://example1.com/index.php?page=pagex`. I am trying to get it to remain at `http://example2.com/pagex`.

Comment: That means 1st rule is also firing which should not happen since it has `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pagex/ [NC]`. Note that I am not using REQUEST_URI which can change by rule's execution. On my testing URL remains `http://example2.com/pagex` in browser but internally it redirects to `http://example2.com/index.php?page=pagex`

Comment: I missed the change to `%{THE_REQUEST}`. I made the correction and `example1.com/pagex/` no longer redirects, however `example1.com/pagex` (no closing slash) does redirect. Can that be fixed?

Comment: Yes added a `?` (optional) to make it `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/pagex/? [NC]` Pls try again, it should work.